# jQuery toggle animation issue

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

Hello i'm trying to a simple toggle animation, but what's hapening is that the '#admin > p' is disapering as soon as the page loads. I want it to dodge the '#admin form' when it's slideUp (witch is working fine) and on the second click it would return to it's original position. Thanks. here is the code:

```
$('#admin > p').click(function(){
  $('#admin > form, #btn').stop(true).slideToggle();
})

$('#admin > p').toggle(function() {
      $(this).animate({'left':'20px'});
    }, function() {
  $(this).animate({'right':'20px'});
    });
```

Comment: Your toggle is being called once, on the page load.  Did you mean for it to be toggled on the click of the #admin > p ?

Comment: Yes, what i really wanted is that with the same click event on 'admin > p' the form and #btn slide up at the same time as the '#admin > p' animation for the left and vice-versa. I tried with the toggle inside the click event but it didn't work as well

Comment: Can we have a fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dW6Mb/... Note: i don't know what's hapening but this is working in my browser. i just wanted to the '#admin > p' goes back to it's original position when the form is hidden

Comment: @Miguel Is [this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/dW6Mb/7/)

Comment: Thanks very much Zach, althou there's a little prob with your fiddle... try to fill the form, hehe. Don't worry i got it. Cheers